# Superman 'Imaginary Story' Late '50s - Early '60's

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

Superman has somehow (red kryptonite, maybe?) lost his powers and is an ordinary mortal, but doesn't want anybody to know it. He is shot in the stomach (just by who, I don't remember) but somehow convinces his assailant he has not been harmed. (Even as a kid I had a hard time swallowing *that* one!) After the assailant leaves Supes staggers away and falls into a fountain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Over four years late with this answer, so this may no longer be useful to you, but on the off chance it is, I believe you were thinking of [Superman Vol 1 #160](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_160), published in 1963.

Near the beginning of the issue, Superman comes into contact with some Red Kryptonite particles, which cause him to lose his powers.

[image]

[image]

Subsequently, he's shot in the torso as part of a charity event, but is protected by his invulnerable costume.

[image]

[image]

Later still, some thieves shoot poison darts and arrows at him, and one of the darts nicks his ear, causing him to become dizzy. After the thieves flee the scene, he staggers away and falls into a river.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it's a cliche, but better late than never. That is the story and thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for confirming that it was the right story. :-)

Comment: I probably threw people off-track by thinking it was an imaginary story. Thanks again.